# Do I need to update gcloud components as indicated in docker startup

Tags: google-cloud-datalab

I get the following warning while starting my docker container for datalab

```
Updates are available for some Cloud SDK components.  To install them,
please run:
  $ gcloud components update
```

Do I need to go inside the container and run this? Is it safe to ignore? Perhaps, is it NOT safe to update?

Not a docker expert so how do I know if a new docker image is available for a container, in this case, the datalab image.

Answer (score 4):

**Short Version**

The notification is expected since a new version of gcloud has been published since the Google Cloud Datalab image `gcr.io/cloud-datalab/datalab:local` was built. You can ignore this notification. It will disappear once a new Google Cloud Datalab image is built and published.

**Long Version**

It will not be helpful to run `gcloud components update` inside the container. Any changes to `gcloud` will be lost when the Docker container is restarted.

The warning (or notification) is expected when a new version of `gcloud` is published. Updates to gcloud occur very frequently so I expect this will be a common notification.

To avoid the possibility of subtle changes to gcloud breaking a working datalab environment, the command `gcloud components update` is executed when the Datalab image `gcr.io/cloud-datalab/datalab:local` is built , rather than at container start up.

You will continue to see the notification until a new version of the Datalab image `gcr.io/cloud-datalab/datalab:local` is published which includes the latest version of `gcloud`.  The Cloud Datalab docker image `gcr.io/cloud-datalab/datalab:local` is managed by the Google Cloud Datalab team. You can find the release notes for Google Cloud Datalab [here](https://github.com/googledatalab/datalab/wiki/Release-Info). You can find the release notes for gcloud (Google Cloud SDK) [here](https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/release/RELEASE_NOTES), along with the date and version of each release. 
Here are a few helpful commands to view the version numbers of `gcloud` and Google Cloud Datalab:

Using the Google Cloud Datalab web interface, click on the `[i]` icon in the top right of the web interface. You should see something like `'Version: 0.5.20160809'`

Alternatively, you can execute the following in a cell:

```
%%bash
echo $DATALAB_VERSION
```

To check to see which version of `gcloud` you are running in the container, execute the following in a cell:

```
%%bash
gcloud version
```

To pull the latest docker Datalab image for `gcr.io/cloud-datalab/datalab:local`, run the following command in terminal:

```
docker pull gcr.io/cloud-datalab/datalab:local
```